# Mac -- HDMI to USB/Thunderbolt

Tags: display, imac, usb, thunderbolt, hdmi

I know there are small USB boxes which are able to pass through image from HDMI (and record it) to computer. Is there something similar which would enable me to see stuff from HDMI on my Mac?

Why: I am trying to discover possibilities how to use iMac, which I might be buying, as a target screen. I read there was this possibility for older iMacs, but only with other Apple computer. I want to connect PS3 or in future maybe some other console/device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, what you are looking for is a [video capture device](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Video_capture).  Mac computers don't have video input so this must be added on.

The way it works is video that is sent out from another source like a game console, DVD player, or even another computer it captured by this device and encoded to video.

One that a client of mine has used and seemed to like very much is this one by [Elgato](http://radnex.us/Elgato_HD60S_Video_Capture)

Now, if you are looking to buy a Mac (I am assuming iMac because of the built in display) and using it as a target screen, it is important to know that while it is possible on ***some*** iMacs, it's not possible on all and only possible with other Mac hardware.  See [Apple Support](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204592) for full details.

If having an external display for other devices is a high priority, don't get an iMac - get a Mac Mini instead and get a high quality monitor with multiple inputs.

Comment: As it is written in my question -- I am talking about iMac. Also in the question I am asking specifically about some external Mac hardware, because I found out that it is not supported feature of iMac by default. I am not sure about the capturing. I don't need to record the image from HDMI. Isn't it what the capturing type of devices do? Thank you for link to the Elgato.

Comment: The part that's confusing is your statement "some external Mac hardware."  That's too broad for me to understand what you are referencing.  As far as you other question, the Elgato Video Capture is what will take the video and put it on the Mac.

Comment: It is so broad for me, because I don't know what to look for ;) But if the Elgato does that job, I have at least starting point if not the final product ;) TY